# Java template: automatically register jsp/jspf

Tags: java, jsp, template-engine

Lets say I'm trying to make some CMS or simple template engine on java.
What I currently have:

Three classes `Block`,`Module` and `Extension` with some differences in it. Everyone of them extends `public abstract class AbstractElement` and mapped with hibernate to the database; Such structure allows to use all this mess later for, for example, user-friendly elements managing (in web site or else), verifying versions and updating them etc.

`public class ElementController`, which works something alike DAO - it retrieves data about registered elements from the database and puts it in HashMaps, allowing them to be accessed from templater class.

Folders like /Database/Templates/{template_name}, where originally templates will be stored. Every template must have `index.jsp`, and so on - basic "templates".

**What I want to do:**
Simple and basic template engine (reed: light). For now, as I can see, there planning to be several JSP tags for templating like `<template:includePanel panel="Left">`or `<template:pageTitle>`. I need just such basics and, as I can see, using JSP tags makes templates be more readable than inserting code (using existing template engine is possible, but still I cant find appropriate);
**The problematic part:** managing blocks or modules. While modules is a big question and, possibly, will be derived to 'plugins' system, blocks is basic elements with no business logic except one found in JSP. Then registering individual "description" class for each of them is a bad design.
Currently, as mentioned above, all blocks description is stored in the database for handling block's settings like panel, which it belongs and order in the panel. Therefore, the only problem situation is autoregistering blocks (i.e. jsp pages).
**Variants I can see:**

Create some custom tag, like

```
<template:block name="BlockName">
...
</template:block>
```

Planned, that this tag will add this block to the templater, which will refresh it's settings from the database if it's already registered or add it to the database. But this won't work, as long as JSP pages compiled at runtime and even then, this tags are not processed. In this case, I need to call each block's JSP before requesting template, which will get blocks info from hash (refreshed). **PROS:** I can define several independent blocks in single page and process them into template with tag's body; There's no need to other code for registering/obtaining info/including block;

Force on creating block's to make it extend some `public class AutoRegister` whith JSP directive `page`. All code for block's registering will be placed in constructor, but in this case I still need to call each block's page separately (Tried to use Reflections for this case, but as long as page is not compiled, it can't be found). Similar to previous variant except for one block per page (jsp/jspf);

Force user to create some 'registrator' class for each block or block's group, and then retrieve information ONLY from the database. **PROS:** all blocks guaranteed registered, no code in block's page except block's logic, registrator class may be derived from some abstract predefined class and automatically called on container's start;**CONS:** there's no opportunity to add or remove blocks without restarting web-app (maybe deployment is possible, but removement will be not so easy), still need to create such registrator even if this is separated block, and not a part of some system/plugin;

Leave all block's require separated class, derived from class Block and parse them through `Reflection` library (this done right now).**CONS:** a lot of 'trash' classes, as long as the only their functions is to register all blocks.
While searching for answers, I had short look on template engines like `Velocity` and `FreeMarker`, but as long as I can see, they can't provide me with such "autoregistration".

**And, at last, the question:**
What method (from described above or some different) or templating engine can provide such mechanism with 'short-and-beauty' usage (like simple JSP tag or something)? Or while trying and testing above variants I missed something?